# BroadcastReceiver when WIFI or 3G network change

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I developed an android app which will update the server database whenever there is a WiFi or 3G network change. I have implemented a `BroadcastReceiver` which listens to `WiFi change or a 3G connectivity change`.

The problem is this code isn't working in Android version 4.x.x. "Internet is connected" toast doesn't appear even after the network is enabled or the wifi is enabled.

It does perfectly work in android 2.3.x and 3.x.x, "Internet is connected" toast appears, and the database is updated too.

This is the `MainActivity.java` file:

```
public class MainActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {   


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Integer flag;
        flag = 0;
        ConnectivityManager check = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] info = check.getAllNetworkInfo();     

        for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
            if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Internet is connected",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                flag = 1;
            }
        }

        if (flag != 0) {

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            m_deviceId = TelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();

            m_androidId = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Secure.ANDROID_ID);

            String bm = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER + ","
                    + android.os.Build.MODEL;
            System.out.println("Device Name: " + bm + "\n");

            try {

                URL url = new URL(
                        "http://saslabtech.com/atsdemo/import_vr.php?d="
                                + URLEncoder.encode(m_deviceId, "UTF-8") + "&a="
                                + URLEncoder.encode(m_androidId, "UTF-8")
                                + "&model=" + URLEncoder.encode(bm, "UTF-8")
                                + "&ip="
                                + URLEncoder.encode(getLocalIpv4Address(), "UTF-8"));
                System.out.println(url);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                readStream(con.getInputStream());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Toast.makeText(context, "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.read"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Please specify what *not working* means

Comment: "Internet is connected" toast doesn't appear even after the network is enabled or the wifi is enabled.

Comment: Please don't create a class called `MainActivity` unless it actually extends the `Activity` class. Also, unless you have an actual MAIN/LAUNCHER `Activity` your users can't start your app and any `BroadcastReceiver` registered in your `AndroidManifest.xml` will never be activated.

Comment: The Toast needs the *activity's context* I guess. You are passing a different context instance. And I totally agree with @Squonk - Please don't  make `MainActivity` extend `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: @MimiPaul: your app will work as expected only below android v 3.1 because since `honeycomb` version, android has made it compulsion to define atleast `an activity` to push the app from `stopped state to active state`.

Comment: @Squonk I changed the class name to `TheReceiver` , but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @MimiPaul : The naming of your class isn't the real issue - my point was it's simply very confusing and if you ever work in a professional programming job, the other programmers wouldn't find it easy to follow your code. My main point was a `BroadcastReceiver` (or any other Android app component) will not be active until the user has started your app at least once. For later versions of Android you *MUST* have a MAIN / LAUNCHER app and the user *MUST* start it at least once. Also, if they ever "Force Stop" your app, the `BroadcastReceiver` will cease to work again.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply check the connectivity as mentioned below:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("Network Monitoring", "onReceive ");

     if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {


            boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(
                    ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);

            if (noConnectivity) {
                return;//you don't have internet connectivity
            }
            //you have internet connectivity, so you may put your code here for further process

        }


}
```